# Is no horizontal scalability when it comes to writing a RDBMS defect? or does it happen to all DBMS'?

Tags: scalability, rdbms, database

When you hit a roof on reading from a database, you have two choices, scale vertically by putting more hardware in the server, or scale horizontally by putting a second server to help offload the reads.

Offloading reads to a second server, means that all writes will hit both servers, while read only hits one.

Problem is when you hit a roof with writing, since writing has to happen to all servers, it means that all servers will be overloaded with write requests, and the server comes unusable. Adding more servers to the problem doesn't help, since it only adds more servers that will be overloaded. So you have to scale vertically.

**Is this something that is specific to RDBMS'? or is it something that happens with all DBMS'?**

I know you can do things on software side, and split the database in two, eg. all entries starting with 0-m in one db while n-z in another, but IMHO it is more of a workaround than a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see that this would be specific to the relational model. All databases that have to read and write (and that's most of them) will have a similar problem.

For what it's worth, most databases are read far more than written so the write roof occurs less frequently than you might think. In addition, load balancing databases as per your method tends to be an immediate write to the primary with queued writes to all secondaries (at least in my experience).

In that case, you're not actually waiting around for multiple writes as a user, you just wait for the first. The DBMS itself manages the synchronisation between instances. This of course means that secondary databases might not be totally up-to-date but this can be controlled. Technically, this breaks the ACID properties of the system as a whole but this can be architected around.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the case with any DBMS, although some handle it better than others.  Like you mention, partitioning the database in software seems to be the most common solution to this.

In many applications though, partitioning the database like that makes sense anyways if you are at such a huge scale that it becomes necessary.  For example, if you had a social networking app, it would probably make sense to partition your database by country or other geographical regions.  This would allow you to have your servers located geographically close to the regions they serve.  It would also help mitigate any problems with a cross-database "social graph" since peoples friends tend to live nearby.

Answer (score 0):

You're hardly going to "hit a roof with writing, since writing has to happen to all server" because in most of RDBMS installations:

1) Reads are overwhelming more frequent than writes

2) Modern RDBMs have Multi-Version Concurrency Control able to reduce blocking when reading/writing